# WordPress and pagination

Tags: pagination

Let me paste code first:

```
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$category_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'post_type'        => array('post', 'shows', 'hosts'),
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'category'         => $category_id
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
?>
    <!-- My Markup was here -->
<?php }
if( function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
?>
```

Everything works fine except pagination (I mean pagenavi). Any suggestion?

Comment: "*Any suggestion?*" - Yes: [search the site for related questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination).

Comment: @ChipBennett, is it possible to make pagination functional keeping get_posts()?